# Get Dropbox accessToken using DbxWebAuth.finish method

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, dropbox-api

I'm trying to complete the oAuth2 trip to get the AccessToken.

I followed [this official guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java) to understand how Java API works, and I'm using [the documentation](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/index.html?com/dropbox/core/DbxSessionStore.html) to understand how class work together, but I'm not able to understand how `com.dropbox.core`.`DbxWebAuth`#`finish(Map<String, String[]> queryParams)`.

I don't understand which values give to `queryParams`.
Do someone explain me?

PS: This is some code that I write to retrive the access token.

```
String accessToken(String code, String state, DbxWebAuth webAuth) {
    DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(????);
    return authFinish.accessToken;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Dropbox Java Core SDK tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java#authenticating) does use `DbxWebAuthNoRedirect` which has a different `finish` method than `DbxWebAuth`:

[`DbxWebAuthNoRedirect.finish`](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxWebAuthNoRedirect.html#finish(java.lang.String))
[`DbxWebAuth.finish`](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxWebAuth.html#finish(java.util.Map))

The `DbxWebAuth.finish` documentation has the following for `queryParams`:

> queryParams - The query parameters on the GET request to your redirectUri.

For a sample of how to use it, the web-file-browser example app included with the SDK uses `DbxWebAuth.finish` as such:

```
    DbxAuthFinish authFinish;
    try {
        authFinish = getWebAuth(request).finish(request.getParameterMap());
    }
```